# Blackberry HTTP Connection Issue

Tags: java, blackberry

I have a simple app written the connects to web service (restful). The app works fine on the blackberry simulator however I'm having problems using it on a blackberry 9300.

I keep getting the error "java.io.ioexception: tunnel down" when the apps attempts to call the web service.

The service I am calling is a simple HTTP post and I'm trying to run this over WIFI (the WIFI connection is working fine for browsing the internet).

I'm using a connection string of "http://127.0.0.1:8080/test/restws;interface=wifi" with the IP address changed to the actual Ip address of the server I'm calling. I can call the restful web service on this server on my laptop browser fine.

The code Im using is similar to below  & works fine on the simulator. The only thing im changing between the simulator and the code on the phone is the connection string (using "interface=wifi" as oppose to "deviceside=true")

Is this a code problem or is it a setting I need to change on the handset? Any ideas on what I need to do to overcome this.

Thanks

```
    StreamConnection s = (StreamConnection) Connector
        .open(connectionString);
    httpConn = (HttpConnection) s;
    httpConn.setRequestMethod("POST");
    httpConn.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", Integer.toString(postData.length()));

    OutputStream output = httpConn.openOutputStream();
    output.write(postData.getBytes());
    output.flush();
    output.close();

    String response = httpConn.getResponseMessage();
    int statusCode = httpConn.getResponseCode();
    if (statusCode != HttpConnection.HTTP_OK) {
    }

    InputStream is = httpConn.openInputStream();
    int ret = 0;
    while ((ret = is.read(buf)) > 0) {
    os.write(buf, 0, ret);
    }

    result = new String(os.toByteArray());
```

Comment: Did you get any solution to your problem Please share. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I had problems in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6382175/blackberry-wifi-http-connection) .After getting HttpConnection everything is the same i guess. Try this:

```
ConnectionFactory cf = new ConnectionFactory();
ConnectionDescriptor cd = cf.getConnection("YourUrl");
httpConnector = (HttpConnection) cd.getConnection();
httpConnector.setRequestMethod(HttpConnection.POST);
```

Comment: Hi Mucie, I tried this and I seem to be getting more or less the same problem. Everything is fine on the simulator but it doesnt work on the actual phone.

Comment: Did you look at [here](http://www.localytics.com/blog/2009/how-to-reliably-establish-a-network-connection-on-any-blackberry-device/).